# How do I predict using my type <torchvision.models> upon my set of images? Python / Torchvision / PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I've trained my images upon my training and validation set, but now I wish to apply my model to my testing set (which I also have the classifications stored). The only way I've seen of even processing the testing set is via the exact same mechanisms of the validation set, but this makes it an extension of the validation set rather than the testing set? There is no prediction.

```
model_ft, hist = train_model(model_ft, dataloaders_dict, criterion, optimizer_ft, num_epochs=num_epochs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below

```
def predict(model, dataloader):  
  # Set model to evaluate mode
  model.eval()   
  predictions = []

  with torch.no_grad()
    # Iterate over data.
    for inputs, _ in dataloader:
      outputs = model(inputs)
      _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
      predictions.extend(preds.numpy())

  return predictions

print (predict(model_ft, your_test_dataloader))
```